# Front load washing machine vibration dampening

Tags: washing-machine, vibration

I have a washing machine in 3rd floor condo of a wooden frame structure that causes substantial vibrations in the floor during the spin cycle. It currently sits on four rubber puck dampeners. [Apparently Consumer Reports investigated these devices and found they do little, but found that a more massive, expensive dampener did remove floor vibrations.](https://www.consumerreports.org/video/view/appliances/laundry/207644082001/stopping-vibrating-washing-machines/) Unfortunately, the [Steadywash](https://www.builderonline.com/products/ohio-steel-industries-steadywash-platform-for-washers-and-dryers_o) seems to be out of production. Are there equivalent solutions currently available?

[image: Steadywash]

I have already tried ensuring the machine is:

1. level
2. evenly loaded, with sufficient clothing in the washer to expect the distribution of mass around the drum is not the direct cause of vibrations

Although similar to [HE Front End Washer vibrations on wood floors: any tried-and-true solutions?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/48026/162828), this question is specifically about the pre-engineered dampening solution for a front-end washer.

I understand that you should not buy a front-end washer to put on the third floor, but the unit came with this washer and I am examining non-replacement options. Consumer Reports itself does not actually recommend the dampener; they say to buy a different washing machine. That's great if I am starting from no washing machine, but I have the previous owner's machine.

Comment: Put it on a set of concrete blocks or pavers or some such massive object?

Comment: strap the washer to the wall

Comment: @mattm: curious as to what you mean by "evenly loaded" w.r.t a front loading machine?  I suspect the issue is the brand/make/model of machine, i.e. if it was not made well to ensure low vibration once it has been leveled correctly, I doubt there is much you will be able to do to reduce.  Do you experience vibration with *every* load?

Answer (score 2):

There are a wide variety of machinery vibration-dampening mounts in various load ratings commonly available (but not at storefront retail outlets, normally.)

Here's a link to a reliable US-Based source of such things. Just a happy customer - you can frequently find similar things cheaper elsewhere for some of what they offer, but often they have things it's hard to find elsewhere at all. In any case, you can look through the offerings and try some, or see what ones are most similar to the thing hidden in a video I'm not going to sit through.

https://www.mcmaster.com/vibration-mounts/

Take your machine's weight, plus the weight of the amount of water it uses and clothing it's rated for, and divide by 4 if it has 4 feet. A vastly over-rated mount won't work well, as it will be too stiff, while an under-rated mount will self-destruct or crush. So you want one just slightly over-rated in order to work and hold up.

It would appear that the product illustrated is a heavy platform on (unseen) mounts, so to replicate that you'd get a hunk of steel, stone, plywood or concrete the size of your washer base, (or big enough to land all the feet, anyway) add its weight to the weights above, and put suitable mounts for the new total weight between that and the floor. You can use as few as 3 mounts, or as many as fit, and divide the load number appropriately on that basis.

A suitable hunk of concrete can be fabricated in place by making a shallow box form (need not disassemble unless you want more than one - you can leave it in place for dry inside service) and mixing concrete right there to fill it. Calculate the weight, apply the mounts, remove the washer, set the box with mounts in place, pour concrete, allow to set, put washer back in place.